# Get a specific value from a json data

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have the `PagesController function` that looks like this:

```
public function home(){
        if (\Session::has('user_id')){
            $posts = DB::table('posts')->get();
            $user = DB::table('users')->where('id', \Session::get('user_id'))->first();
            return view('home', compact('posts', 'user'));
        }else{
            return view('welcome');
        }
    }
```

And, in my view `home.blade.php`, when I print out the data using `{{$user->user_json}}`, I get:

```
{"id":6,"friends":[],"posts":[],"messages":[],"notifications":[],"pin":""}
```

So now, How do I get a specific value like the id of the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$json = json_decode($user->user_json, true);
{{$json['id']}}
```

Or

```
$obj= json_decode($user->user_json);
$obj->id;
```

Try the above code it will work.

Comment: I got an error saying:
`Illegal string offset 'id' (View: /home/seeker/Desktop/explore.com.np/resources/views/home.blade.php)`

Comment: The variable user is said to be object and it couldn't be decoded!

Comment: so user is an object and what about user_json

Comment: user_json is also object! I checked using **gettype** function

Comment: try this...
https://jonsuh.com/blog/convert-loop-through-json-php-javascript-arrays-objects/

Answer (score 1):

If you sent json, you have to decode in the blade and it will return an associative array as we passed true in the second parameter

$user_data = json_decode($user_json, true);

Comment: "The data I got is an object and it cannot be decoded", says Laravel

Comment: That worked but I **json_encoded ($user->user_json) ** instead! and that was how it worked!